# How Get PowerBuilder icons

Tags: powerbuilder

everyone!

How can I get standard PowerBuilder icons like files with *.ico extension. F.e. Find! or Help! icon like on the picture.

[image: Some icon like this one]

Answer (score 1):

They are embedded in the application.  You need to use a tool which extracts icons from compiled applications or use a graphic capture tool and make them yourself.

Comment: I like IcoFX for extracting icons. Haven't tried it with Powerbuilder icons, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the button `...` on the right of your image, you will be prompted a list of images file types that are supported.  As Matt Balent says, you can also use a tool to extract icon files from existing windwos libraries (like moricons.dll).  Here is a small list of libraries that can be usefull:

```
compstui.dll
DDORes.dll
ieframe.dll
imageres.dll
mmcndmgr.dll
moricons.dll
netshell.dll
pnidui.dll
shell32.dll
wmploc.DLL
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's what you need:

- PB 10 icons (https://www.appeon.com/files/pb10iconszip-0)
- the Silk icons (https://www.appeon.com/files/silk-iconszip)
- the WinXP icons (https://www.appeon.com/files/winxp-iconszip)